# How to remove the launch screen in IPhone - IBM MobileFirst

Tags: android, ios, iphone, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to implement custom splash screen using IBM Mobilefirst for both Android/IPhone platforms.

My requirement is to show a GIF image on app launch.

In Android, custom splash screen is perfectly working. But in IPhone, before showing the GIF image, the default splash screen is displaying.

From this blog https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/creating_a_rich_hybrid_application_ui_with_ibm_worklight_foundation_6_2?lang=en , I got one sample application. When I run this project in android, there is no splash screen is displaying. But the same project in IPhone displays splash image before displaying the custom page.

I want to remove that default splash screen and only show the custom spalsh screen.

Comment: AFAIK iOS requires a launch screen when the app starts, you could take the first frame of your gif and use it as launch screen, then you'll take the user to your custom splash screen that actually shows the gif.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you'll need to at least have the image, and then use it in a different way.

Follow this tutorial to add native UI to your MobileFirst-based Hybrid app: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/adding-native-functionality/ios-adding-native-ui-elements-hybrid-applications/